# Google Forms - Prefill multiple-choice list based on jobs assigned to Google Apps for Business User

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-forms

I'm exploring the possibility of using Google Forms to capture the hours spent on specific job codes for a couple hundred employees.

Each employee has a Google Apps for Business account, so I know the form can capture their username (not sure if it is captured before or after the form is submitted, though).

Each employee has a number of job codes assigned to them, but not all necessarily the same job code. I'm wondering if I can use Google Forms, Google Sheets, and some Google Apps script to populate a multiple-choice dropdown list in the form based on the jobs assigned to that employee when they load the form, so all they see are the job codes that are assigned to them.

Is this possible? How should I go about a solution?

I've explored pre-filled URLs, the formRanger Add On and the answers @Mogsdad provided to a couple of similar questions - all awesome by thesmselves, but but none seemed to be an exact fit. Thank you for any feedback you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The Go To Page logic in Google Forms can conditionally control what pages of questions to show based on a previous dropdown selection [employee name], not who is actually logged in. You can try using 1 Google Form with a separate page for each employee.

A single-page web app built with Google Apps Script can recognize the user and dynamically change dropdown options after it has been opened based on who is logged in. You'll need to write the front-end JS logic for this and lots of other parts.